# How to Set Horizontal Alignment On A Table In Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am not able to find a way to horizontally align a table in a Google Doc using Google Apps Script. I have thoroughly checked all of the documentation, and also blindly tried several approaches.

Attempt One:

```
var cells = [
  ['Company', rowData[3]],
  ['Title', rowData[4]],
];

var tableStyle = {};
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;

var mentorTable = body.appendTable(cells);

var myTable = body.appendTable(cells);
myTable.setAttributes(tableStyle);
```

Attempt Two:

```
var cells = [
  ['Company', rowData[3]],
  ['Title', rowData[4]],
];

var mentorTable = body.appendTable(cells);
myTable.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
```

The Google Docs UI supports changing this attribute from the "Table Properties" menu option.

Any thoughts on how to align a table using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Feature request for table centering via Apps Script added to Google tracker, you can "star" it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765133

Answer (score 5):

I realize this question is relatively old, but I found the following worked for me. Rather than setting the alignment directly on the cell, I need to set it the child.

```
// create table
table = body.appendTable();

// add row
var tr = table.appendTableRow();

// add cell and right align
var td = tr.appendTableCell('hello world!');
td.getChild(0).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
```

Comment: It seems to me that HorizontalAligment is a **paragraph attribute**, not a cell attribute, therefore, you need to get the text using asParagraph. In fact, when you modify horizontal alignment manually, you go to the paragraph style bar, not to the table options menu.

Answer (score 0):

I also though you could do it setting the attributes to the complete table, but i could only do it getting the content of each cell and then add the attribute.

In the following code I look for the tables in the document, go to each cell and then apply the formatting.  I know this shouldn't be like that but couldn't find a easier way to do it.

Hope it helps.

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

   var style = {};
   style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;

  var body  = doc.getBody();

  for(var i = 0 ; i < body.getNumChildren(); i++)
  {
    if(body.getChild(i).getType() ==  'TABLE')
    {
      var table = body.getChild(i).asTable();
      var rows = table.getNumRows();
      var cols = table.getChild(0).asTableRow().getNumChildren();

      for(var j =0 ; j< rows; j++)
      {
        for(var k =0; k<cols; k++)
        {
          body.getChild(i).asTable().getCell(j,k).getChild(0).setAttributes(style);
        }      
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Gerardo. This appears to right-align every cell in the table. I want to actually align the table itself to the right within the document.