# How do I center a table in a google document page using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have inserted a table in a google docs using the Google Apps Script function

```
var grg = body.appendTable(griglia);
```

I am able to format the text in the table (font size, weight, alignment) and I can format individual cells (background, foreground, borders).

However the table is aligned left, and I would like it to be (horizontally) centered in the page.
From the google docs user interface this can be done from the menu "Table>Table properties", which generates a dialog box with a dropdown menu for "Table alignment".

I cannot find a way to obtain the same from the script.
I tried

```
var grg = body.appendTable(griglia).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

but I get an error because the setAlignment function is not defined for a table (this works for paragraphs).

I also tried by defining a style

```
  var gTxt={};
  gTxt[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
  grg.setAttribute(gTxt);
```

but this does not seem to produce any effect on the table.
Actually I also tried with a different property, just to try to understand how things work.

Using

```
gTxt[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#ff0000';
grg.setAttribute(gTxt);
```

all the text in the table, and whatever follows it, becomes red. So it seems that the setAttributes is not "limited" to the table.
I am confused, because [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setAttributes(Object)) "setAttributes" is listed under "Table" (although in the example it is used on a paragraph).

I did extensive research, but found only one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525029/how-to-set-horizontal-alignment-on-a-table-in-apps-script) (in fact basically identical) dating back two years.
As far as I understand from this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299670/how-can-i-revive-a-long-dead-question), my question should not be marked as a duplicate, since the older question was not really answered.

There is only an answer, but its author misunderstood the question.
The point here is centering the table, and not the text in its cells (which I can do no problem).

I tried to upvote or comment the old question, but was not able because I have only a few points.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to center table *via Apps Script* at the moment.

There's feature request created in Google tracker, you can "star" it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765133

Comment: Yes, I was starting to suspect that. This is unfortunate. I'll definitely "star" that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I notice that the issue has been starred by 3 people only. Perhaps it would be convenient to answer/comment the question from 2 years back, but I'm not sure this is the right thing to do, because the old unanswered question is now linked to this one.  I have too few points to comment, and I would not answer because it's you that pointed out the "answer". But the more interested people is aware of the issue, the more could star it.

Comment: @PFB no worries, I have added link in the comment to that question

Comment: Well, it's 2022 and feature request has 47 "stars"

Answer (score 1):

A potential workaround is to insert your table into another 3 column table, with hidden borders. By default the 3 column table will fill the entire width of the page, so the middle cell is naturally centered.

```
 body.appendTable([['','','']])
       .setBorderWidth(0)
       .getCell(0,1)
       .appendTable([['one','two','three']]);
```

You could further tweak the positioning by adjusting the width of column 0 in the outer table.

Comment: Hi Cameron, this is interesting, thanks. I'm going to experiment with your suggestion, but I am not sure that the the second table would be centered in the central cell.  After all my table is already in a centered paragraph, and yet it is not centered. I suspect that this has to do with the fact that I modified the column widths of my table.

Comment: Hi Cameron, this is interesting, thanks. I'm going to experiment with your suggestion, but I am not sure that the the second table would be centered in the central cell.  After all my table is already in a centered paragraph, and yet it is not centered. I suspect that this has to do with the fact that I modified the column widths of my table.